# How to calculate the energy of a spring-mass system considering harmonic oscillation of the normal mode?

Tags: classical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, frequency, coupled-oscillators, normal-modes

For a spring-mass system, we know that the potential and kinetic energy are
$$E_p = \frac{1}{2}ku^2 \text{ and } E_k = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{u}^2.$$
where $k$, $m$ and $u$ are the spring constant, mass and the displacement of the mass. If we consider harmonic motion of the normal mode, we have that
$$ u(t) = \hat{u}\, \mathrm{e}^{i\omega t},$$
where $\omega = \sqrt{k/m}$ is the natural frequency. If we substitute this equation into the energy formulas above, we get
$$ E_p = \frac{1}{2}k\hat{u}^2\mathrm{e}^{2i\omega t} \text{ and } E_k = -\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\hat{u}^2\mathrm{e}^{2i\omega t}. $$
Substituting the natural frequency yields
$$ E_p = \frac{1}{2}k\hat{u}^2\mathrm{e}^{2i\omega t} \text{ and } E_k = -\frac{1}{2}k\hat{u}^2\mathrm{e}^{2i\omega t}. $$
However, this is clearly wrong since the total energy $E=E_p+E_k$ would be zero. Besides, we know that $E$ should be constant over time and equal the maximum kinetic or potential energy ($E =\frac{1}{2}k\hat{u}^2$). What am I doing wrong? How can one calculate the energy of a spring-mass system considering harmonic oscillation of the normal mode?

I don't have a solid background in physics, so, please, be as clear as possible.

Motivation: the question relevancy lies on being able to use Euler's representation to calculate energies. Although the stated problem is simple and could be solved using trigonometric functions, Euler's representation is much more convenient when dealing with complex problems -- such as multi-degree-of-freedom systems -- and the answer to the question could be extended to such problems.

Comment: You can't have complex values for either the kinetic energy or the potential energy. So, the appearance of $e^{2i\omega t}$ in, say, the kinetic energy should be a strong hint that you messed up big time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we have that
> $$ u(t) = \hat{u}\, \mathrm{e}^{i\omega t},$$

When we write something like this, what we really mean is that the actual displacement is the *real* part:
$$
u(t) = \Re(\hat u e^{i\omega t})
$$
and we should introduce some new notation for a new complex displacement like:
$$
\tilde u(t) = \hat u e^{i\omega t}
$$

Given the definition:
$$
u(t) = \Re(\hat u e^{i\omega t}) = \frac{1}{2}(\hat u e^{i\omega t} + \hat u^* e^{-i\omega t})
$$
we have:
$$
E_p = \frac{k}{8}\left(\hat u^2 e^{i2\omega t} + {\hat u^*}^2 e^{-i2\omega t} + 2|\hat u|^2\right) = \frac{k}{4}\left(\Re(\hat u^2e^{i2\omega t})+|\hat u|^2\right)
$$
and
$$
E_k = \frac{-\omega^2 m}{8}\left(\hat u^2 e^{i2\omega t} +{\hat u^*}^2e^{-i2\omega t} - 2|\hat u|^2\right) = \frac{\omega^2m}{4}\left(-\Re({\hat u^2e^{i2\omega t}})+|\hat u|^2\right)
$$

Now, with $\omega ^2 m = k$ we have
$$
E = E_k+E_p = \frac{k}{4}2|\hat u|^2 = \frac{1}{2}k|\hat u|^2\;,
$$
as expected.

If we want to emphasize how the fixed total energy E sloshes back and forth between (real) kinetic energy  and (real) potential energy, we could write:
$$
E_k(t) = E/2 -\frac{k}{4}\Re({\hat u^2e^{i2\omega t}})
$$
$$
E_p(t) = E/2 +\frac{k}{4}\Re({\hat u^2e^{i2\omega t}})
$$

Answer (score 1):

The position of a spring-mass system is real valued function of time, not complex. When you write down the normal mode, you need to specify that you are taking the real part of the complex expression:
$$
u(t) = \text{Re}\left(\hat u e^{i\omega t} \right) = A \cos(\omega t + \delta).
$$
Here, $A = |\hat u|$ is the amplitude of the oscillation and $\delta$ is an unimportant phase shift.

The time derivative of this expression gives
$$
\dot u(t) = \text{Re}\left(i\omega \hat u e^{i\omega t} \right) = - \omega A \sin(\omega t + \delta).
$$

If we compute the potential and kinetic energy using these two expressions we get
$$
E_p = {1 \over 2} k A^2 \cos^2(\omega t+\delta),
~~~~~
E_k = {1 \over 2} m \omega^2 A^2 \sin^2(\omega t+\delta).
$$

Using $\omega^2 = k/m$, the total energy is then
$$
E = E_p + E_k = {1 \over 2} k A^2 (\cos^2(\omega t+\delta)+\sin^2(\omega t+\delta)) = {1 \over 2} k A^2,
$$
which is constant in time, as we expect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, shouldn't I get the same result by taking the real part of the final expression for E, instead of carrying out operations with sin and cos?
It would be much better for my application if I could carry out operations with Euler's representation...

Comment: @R.Thomes The real part of a square is not the same as the square of a real part. Consider $z=x+iy$. The real part of $z^2$ is $x^2-y^2$. The real part of $z$ is $x$, and that squared is $x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Euler's representation, but the general solution comes from a second order differential equation, which requires 2 arbitrary constants.

$$ u(t) = \hat{u}_1\, \mathrm{e}^{i\omega t} + \hat{u}_2\, \mathrm{e}^{-i\omega t}$$
Note that $u(t)$ is real $\implies u = u^* \implies$$\hat{u}_1$ and $\hat{u}_2$ are complex conjugates. What implies that $E_p$ and $E_k$ are also real, and $E$ is real and constant:

$$u^2 = \hat{u}_1^2\, \mathrm{e}^{2i\omega t} + \hat{u}_2^2\, \mathrm{e}^{-2i\omega t} + 2\hat{u}_1\hat{u}_2 = (\hat{u}_1\, \mathrm{e}^{i\omega t} + \hat{u}_2\, \mathrm{e}^{-i\omega t})^2$$
$$\dot{u}^2 = -\omega^2\hat{u}_1^2\, \mathrm{e}^{2i\omega t} - \omega^2\hat{u}_2^2\, \mathrm{e}^{-2i\omega t} + 2\omega^2\hat{u}_1\hat{u}_2 = -\omega^2(\hat{u}_1\, \mathrm{e}^{i\omega t} - \hat{u}_2\, \mathrm{e}^{-i\omega t})^2$$

$$E = E_p + E_k = 2k\hat{u}_1\hat{u}_2 $$

There are 2 particular cases for the phase shift:
When $\hat{u}_1 = \hat{u}_2 = \hat{u}$, they are real:
$u = \hat{u}(\mathrm{e}^{i\omega t} + \mathrm{e}^{-i\omega t}) = 2\hat{u}cos(\omega t)$
When $\hat{u}_1 = -\hat{u}_2$, they are pure imaginary:
$u = -i\hat{u}(\mathrm{e}^{i\omega t} - \mathrm{e}^{-i\omega t}) = 2\hat{u}sin(\omega t)$

For both cases, the constant that multiplies the trigonometric function is $2\hat{u}$, and the energy becomes $$E = 2k\hat{u}_1\hat{u}_2 = 2k\hat{u}^2 = \frac{1}{2}k(2\hat{u})^2$$